# Salesforce automated testing techniques

Tags: unit-test, test-automation

I am a Salesforce QA tester and as all my testing has been manual up to this point, I am interested to learn how to automate some of the new upcoming features and possibly existing processes on Salesforce sales cloud we have built/updated.
I would be looking to automate tests for the creation of specific types of new contacts/companies/addresses/leads. I was not sure if  I would need external software like selenium or be able to use any Salesforce internal apps like workflow or process builder.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Selenium can be used, and is typically the tool for "functional testing" (a "higher level" or rather "more abstract" test that covers things like "when a user presses this button, they should be taken to a new page and see thing X").

Process Builder and Workflow aren't testing tools, and part of the appeal of using declarative functionality (like those two, and more) is that they *don't need tests written for them*. You can certainly write tests for them though (and I'd argue that's good practice).

For that, you'd likely be writing test classes and test methods in Apex.

You should go through the [various modules on testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/search?keywords=testing) over on trailhead to get started.

Answer (score 0):

If your company allows, you may try - [Provar Tool](https://www.provartesting.com/)
It is a paid tool. This is built for Salesforce test automation, so you may use it with more comfort.